Searching for function definitions/calls etc
I recently came across a big project I need to disect. In the past, one of the first things I would do is create a tags table to search for function definitions (using etags) , Now it seemed to me you could do this in lsp-mode, but my attempts have been to naught.
Do I need to go back to using etags?
Is there a more recent/updated version of tags I can use?
Is there maybe a replacement to tags?

LSP is a protocol, a way for your editor to send queries to a type of program known as a Language Server. The editor knows nothing at all about the language, it merely relies on whatever answers are sent by the Language Server. You need to figure out what Language Server you are using and read its documentation to learn what features it has and how it operates.

I'll bite. What command in either lsp-mode or eglot allows me to search for the function "the_bestest_function" in a project of a thousand source files? I use ccls but I am willing to change to clangd if needed, but if the mode doesn't give me the function it doesn't matter whether the server supports the feature.

They both hook in to xref-find-references, same as if you had loaded a TAGS file.

Nope it does not. It only finds the reference when it is in the same file. I;'ve tried it.

If there is a configuration oiption that lets me set or unset global search for lsp-mode/servers let me know.

No, there is no configuration option like that. You need to find out which language server you are using, and read its documentation. it has its own configuration independent of Emacs.
